Open iPhone Watch App URL from Custom App in SwiftUI
I want to open the Watch app present in the iPhone.
I searched and tried the following url:
Button("Open Watch App") {
    if let url = URL(string: "itms-watch://") {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
         } else {
             // Handle the case where the Watch app is not installed
             print("Watch app is not installed.")
         }
     }
}

But this url is opening App store. What will be the url to open the Watch app.


Same question... any luck?
